# "Потому что" и "и если" в одном придаточном, - что с запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация

> ...То, укладывая товар, он громко перечислит его вслух и впадёт в
>   глубокую задумчивость – заставит усомниться в кулинарных способностях
>   важной матроны. То откажет посетителю в обслуживании, **потому что он
>   вчера уже был и если он будет так часто заглядывать, то другим ничего
>   не достанется**. То высмеивает диалекты – это важная часть итальянской
>   жизни (выговор у всякого региона свой), ох, не попадись ему южанин или
>   северянин!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То откажет посетителю в обслуживании, потому что он вчера уже был, и ***если он будет так часто заглядывать, то другим ничего не достанется.***

Запятая  ставится между двумя СПП, это соответствует интонации (наличию паузы). Вариант с однородными придаточными причины не подойдет, так как второе СПП оформлено как единое целое составным союзом ЕСЛИ...ТО.

Сравнить: *То откажет посетителю в обслуживании, **потому что он вчера уже был и другим ничего не достанется,** если он будет так часто заглядывать*

Comment: А если в исходном предложении убрать "то" - запятая передвинется через "и" или их станет две?

Comment: Думаю, что запятая всё равно будет нужна, здесь пауза будет в любом случае. И по смыслу  придаточное условное  относится  ко второму причинному предложению, а не к паре, соединенной союзом И.

Comment: Я не припомню правил, по которым запятая обязательно ставилась бы на основании одной только интонации. В одних случаях место постановки запятой (по какому-л. основанию) совпадает с интонационной паузой, в других (после "и" - как здесь в случае без "то") явно противоречит интонации. Возникает парадокс: запятая перед "и", призванная обозначить паузу, оказывается не в состоянии "справиться" с запятой после "и" (случай без "то"). По смыслу и типу подчинённости (через "потому что") я не различаю исходное предложение и вариант с перенесением "встроенного" придаточного (оно условно изымаемо).

Comment: Если убрать составной союз, то формально союз И будет соединять  причинное и условное придаточное, а это неверно. Если оставить составной союз, то союз И будет соединять придаточное и ССП, а это тоже неверно. В этом решении я не использую интонацию вообще.

Comment: На мой взгляд, "и" соединяет два придаточных ("потому что был" и "потому что не достанется"; во втором опущено "потому что"), причём второе придаточное имеет подчинённый оборот с "если... то".

Comment: Если Вы проводите грамматический анализ, то приходите к такому выводу. А я говорю, что ФОРМАЛЬНО у Вас два разных  придаточных соединены союзом И. Вы, думаю, понимаете, что формальная сторона в русском языке важна (к примеру, на нее многие правила сочетаемости слов ориентированы). А если вспомнить всё-таки про интонацию (Вы же будете это предложение читать), то оно будет состоять из трех фраз, причем вторая фраза соединит неоднородные придаточные. И именно это увидят читающие и услышат слушающие. Им-то дела нет до  правил Розенталя и грамматического анализа, это всё забота автора и редактора.